# Codeigniter Active Record - Return Results where Row in Another Table Matches Criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I've had a break from coding and unfortunately drawing a blank here. I'm running the query below then processing the data to filter for unique user IDs, but it's pulling far too much information due to the join command.
I don't need the data from the 'user' table in my query result, just the data from the linked accounts table, but where user.suspended_by (in the user table) is NULL.

```
$this->db
  ->select('*')
  ->from('linked_accounts')
  ->where('primary_user_id', $primary_user_id)
  ->join('user', 'user.id = linked_accounts.linked_account1_user_id')
  ->where('user.suspended_by', NULL);

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

How do I rewrite this query?

Answer: I resolved this, getting rid of the unnecessary information by adding

```
 ->group_by('linked_account1_user_id')
```

Which made the resultant post-processing of data much quicker, because the volume of data returned was much smaller.

Comment: use select ('linked_accounts.*')

Comment: Ill perhaps have to run 2 separate queries, the first to check if the user.id is suspended, and then only if not suspended select the records from the linked_accounts table?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$this->db->select('*')` 
" * " is used for all getting all the records from all the tables included in joins, in your scenario you are using " * " instead of this you can use

```
$columns = array('linked_accounts.*');
$this->db->select($columns)
```